# Must each new year always contain a Friday the 13th?

Tags: calendar-computations

I am wondering if there is any way to determine whether it is possible to have a year that does not contain a Friday the 13th?

Comment: There is and it's not that hard.

Comment: It isn't; a year always has at least one Friday the 13th.  Take March as the base month.  June is March plus one day of the week; September is March plus two; April is March plus three; October is March plus four; May is March plus five; and August is March plus six.

Comment: Of course there is a way to determine that. The exact sequence of weekdays and dates in the Gregorian calendar repeats unchanged every 400 years, so _at worst_ you'd need to inspect 400 different years to find your answer.

Comment: The calendar of a year is determined by the day of the week on which January $1$ falls, and whether or not it's a leap year, so there are only $14$ possible calendars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it.

Tedious but easy way:

Jan 1. must fall on a monday, tues,....., sunday.  And either there is or there is not a leap year.  So there are only $14$ possible calendars.  Check them all.  They all have at least one friday the $13$ths.

Same idea but a bit more efficient.

Suppose it isn't a leap year.  And assume that January first is on a day of the week we call $0$.

January has $31= 4*7 + 3$ days.  So February first will fall on the day of the week $3$.

February has $28 =4*7 + 0$ days.  So March 1 falls on day $3$.

March has $31=4*7+3$ days.  So April 1 fall on day $6$.

April has $30=4*7+2$ days. So May 1 falls on day $8$ but the week has only $7$ days so it  wraps around back to $1$.

And so on.

We get the 12 months start on the following days for the first of the month:  $(0, 3,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5)$.  If it were a leap year we would get $(0, 3,4,0,2,5,0,3,6,1,4,6)$

The $13$th of every month would fall on the following days.  $(6, 2,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,4)$ and $(6, 2,3,6,1,4,6,2,5,0,3,5)$.

Everday day from $0$ to $6$ is possible so xxxday the $13$th will always occur.

===

If Jan. 1st is a Sunday, and it isn't a leap year then April and July will have Friday the 13ths.  If Jan. 1st is a Monday then September and December will have Friday the 13ths.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whether leap year or not, May, June, July, August, September, October, and November start on different days of the week. The month that starts on a Sunday will have a Friday the $13^\text{th}$.
$$
\newcommand{\Sun}{\color{#C00}{\text{Sun}}} \newcommand{\Mon}{\text{Mon}} \newcommand{\Tue}{\text{Tue}} \newcommand{\Wed}{\text{Wed}} \newcommand{\Thu}{\text{Thu}} \newcommand{\Fri}{\text{Fri}} \newcommand{\Sat}{\text{Sat}}
\begin{array}{c|c}
&\text{May}&\text{Jun}&\text{Jul}&\text{Aug}&\text{Sep}&\text{Oct}&\text{Nov}\\
\hline2005&\Sun&\Wed&\Fri&\Mon&\Thu&\Sat&\Tue\\
\hline2000&\Mon&\Thu&\Sat&\Tue&\Fri&\Sun&\Wed\\
\hline2001&\Tue&\Fri&\Sun&\Wed&\Sat&\Mon&\Thu\\
\hline2002&\Wed&\Sat&\Mon&\Thu&\Sun&\Tue&\Fri\\
\hline2003&\Thu&\Sun&\Tue&\Fri&\Mon&\Wed&\Sat\\
\hline2009&\Fri&\Mon&\Wed&\Sat&\Tue&\Thu&\Sun\\
\hline2004&\Sat&\Tue&\Thu&\Sun&\Wed&\Fri&\Mon\\
\hline\end{array}\\
\text{Day of the $1^\text{st}$ of Each Month}
$$

Comment: Note that this question was asked on Friday the $13^\text{th}$.